# How to make it so when an object is called without calling any of its properties, it returns a default value

Tags: javascript

So I have an object called settings with a property called hex, which has its own properties:

```
var settings = {
   hex: {
      hex: "4fdaef",
      validate: function(){
         if(this.hex.length == 6){
            return true
         }
      }
   }
}
```

So currently to get the value of hex I would have to call settings.hex.hex, however ideally I would prefer to be able to call just settings.hex to get the value of the hex. How would I achieve this?

Comment: If `settings.hex` returns a string, then how would you expect to call `validate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to rename `hex` to `_hex`, but this will work:

```js
var settings = {
  get hex() {
    return this._hex.hex;
  },
  _hex: {
    hex: "4fdaef",
    validate: function () {
      if (this.hex.length == 6) {
        return true
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(settings.hex); // 4fdaef
```

With a `Proxy` you can allow for `settings.hex.validate()` to call `_settings._hex._hex.validate()`, but it's getting real ugly real quick, and we haven't even yet implemented the `setter` necessary for expected behavior of `settings.hex = 'some other color'`.

```js
var _settings = {
  _hex: {
    _hex: new String('4fdaef'),
    validate: function () {
      if (this.length == 6) {
        return true;
      }
    },
  }
}

_settings._hex.hex = new Proxy(_settings._hex._hex, {
  get(target, property) {
    return property == 'validate' ? _settings._hex.validate : target[property];
  }
});

const settings = new Proxy(_settings, {
  get(target, property) {
    return property == 'hex' ? target._hex.hex : target[property];
  }
});

console.log(settings.hex); // [String: '4fdaef']
console.log(settings.hex.validate()); // true
```

Comment: Okay so I suppose I didn't quite elaborate enough. If possible I'd still want to be able to call settings.hex.validate() instead of settings._hex.validate(). sorry for not being clear enough!

Comment: I updated the answer.  It's probably not what you expect.